# Own C++ condition_variable class working?

Tags: c++, c++11, condition-variable

To better understand the internal behaviour of a condition_variable in C++11, I tried to write my own (simple/primitive) condition-variable class. It looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class condVar {
public:
    void wait(unique_lock<mutex> & ul) {
        stop_list_mutex.lock(); // synchronize with other wait/noify calls

        ul.unlock();

        // store mutex so we can unlock it afterwards
        shared_ptr<mutex> stopm(new mutex());
        stop_list.push_back(stopm);
        stopm->lock();

        stop_list_mutex.unlock();

        // Stop now ...
        stopm->lock();    
        ul.lock();
    }

    template<typename Predicate>
    void wait(unique_lock<mutex> & ul, Predicate p) {
        while (!p()) wait(ul);
    }

    void notify_one() {
        lock_guard<mutex> lg(stop_list_mutex);
        if (stop_list.size() > 0) {
            stop_list.front()->unlock();
            stop_list.erase(stop_list.begin());
        }
    }

    void notify_all() {
        lock_guard<mutex> lg(stop_list_mutex);
        while (stop_list.size() > 0) {
            stop_list.front()->unlock();
            stop_list.erase(stop_list.begin());
        }
    }

private:

    mutex stop_list_mutex;
    vector<shared_ptr<mutex>> stop_list;
};
```

Some simple tests show no difference in behaviour compared to the 'real' C++11 condition_variable. Would the implemention above work in theory (besides the fact that I have left out lots of error checking code like pre- and post-conditions)?

Comment: You should better ask such questions on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Your `wait()` function doesn't look right to me.  If someone calls `notify` after you unlock `ul` but before you lock `stop_list_mutex` the notification will be lost.

Comment: Just edited the question so that the `stop_list_mutex` is locked right at the beginning of wait()...

Comment: [From documentation on `lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/lock): "If lock is called by a thread that already owns the mutex, the behavior is undefined". [And for `unlock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/unlock): "The mutex must be locked by the current thread of execution, otherwise, the behavior is undefined." Your implementation relies heavily on undefined behavior.

Comment: @Igor: Yes, you are absolutely right. Still its interesting for me that the implementation does not show any false behaviour on my Linux machine (64bit i7 CPU), even with bigger examples including 50+ threads.

Comment: Likely won't work on Windows, where the underlying OS primitive for `std::mutex` (namely, `CRITICAL_SECTION`) is recursive (meaning, the second lock by the same thread just sails through; and unlock by the "wrong" thread fails without doing anything). In other words, on Windows `std::mutex` behaves the same as `std::recursive_mutex`. It just so happens that on your particular platform, the implementation details of `std::mutex` match your intuition.